# How to hover a mouse on to element in FireFox with new WATIR?

Tags: firefox, watir, watir-webdriver, page-object-gem

Can not hover mouse on to element in FireFox with new Watir 6.1.0. `hover` method doesn't work. I have:

- Watir 6.1.0
- FireFox 50.1.0

New method `move_to` doesn't want to work also.

I use next method:

```
  def hover_my_account
    self.spnMyAccount_element.when_present.hover
  end
```

Where `spnMyAccount` described as:

```
  span(:spnMyAccount, xpath: "//span[text()='MY ACCOUNT']")
```

And get next error:

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownCommandError: POST /session/1d9f3178-8059-4b3b-98fa-09d09f38bfa5/moveto did not match a known command
Build info: version: '3.0.1', revision: '1969d75', time: '2016-10-18 09:48:19 -0700'
System info: host: 'VM_WIN10_1', ip: '192.168.13.131', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_101'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
```

Comment: What happens?  Do you get an error?  What version of geckodriver are you using?

Comment: I use 0.13.0 geckodriver. In Chrome 55 it works.